# Returning not found values in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm working on a project, and I have a list of several thousand records that I need check.  I need to provide the list of the ones NOT found, and provide the query I use to locate them so my superiors can check their work.

I'll admit I'm relatively new to SQL. I don't have access to create temporary tables, which is one way I had thought of to do this.

A basic idea of what I'm doing:

```
select t.column1, t.column2
from table1 t
where t.column1 in ('value1','value2','value3')
```

If value1 and value3 are in the database, but value2 is not, I need to display value2 and not the others.

I have tried `ISNULL`, embedding the query, and trying to select `NOT` values from the query.

I have searched for returning records not found in a query on Google and on this site, and still found nothing.

Comment: What can you create on the server full tables, views, store procedure,..? what type of sql is it?

Comment: Does "select t.column1, t.column2
from table1 t
where t.column1 NOT in ('value1','value2','value3')" work for you?  If you only have thousands of items, you can put them in an in list like that.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried something similar:

First create a table which will contain all such values that you need.

lets say

```
create table table_values(values varchar2(30));
```

then try the in clause as below:

```
select * from table_values tv where tv.value not in (select t.column1
from table1 t);
```

this will return the values needed.

Comment: In 1st post he mentioned no tmp tables!

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2008, you can make derived tables using the syntax `VALUES(...)(...)(...)`, e.g.

```
    select v.value
      from (
           values ('value1'),('value2'),('value3')
           ) v(value)
 left join table1 t on t.column1 = v.value
     where t1.column1 is null
```

Notes:

1. Each (...) after VALUES is a single row, and you can have multiple columns.
2. The `v(value)` after the derived table is the alias given to the table, and column name(s).
3. LEFT JOIN keeps the values from the derived table `v` even when the record doesn't exist in table1
4. Then, we keep only the records that cannot be matched, i.e. `t1.column1 is null`
5. I've switched the first column in your select to the column from `v`. column2 is removed because it is always null

Answer (score 1):

solution might work in Oracle where dual is single row single column table. You need
one table where you can make virtual select of desired values!

**WARNING as I don't have access to db I never tested query below.**

```
SELECT tab_all.col_search, t.column1, t.column2
FROM
(
   Select value1 AS col_search from dual
   union all
   Select value2 from dual
   union all
   Select value3 from dual
) tab_all left join  table1 t
on col_search = t.column1
WHERE t.column1 is null;
```

I belive sqlserver equivalent of Oracle's 
SELECT value1 FROM dual is
SELECT value1 OR SELECT 'value1'.

So try

```
SELECT tab_all.col_search, t.column1, t.column2
FROM
(
   Select value1 AS col_search
   union all
   Select value2 AS col_search
   union all
   Select value3 AS col_search
) tab_all left join  table1 t
on col_search = t.column1
WHERE t.column1 is null;
```

As I am not sqlserver person might be that 
RichardTheKiwi version of Oracle's select from dual is better.

Comment: Fair enough, it's SQL Server 2008 R2.  I should have specified we're restricted to T-SQL. I'm fairly restricted to only selects, updates, inserts and deletes, I can't access stored procedures (though I've found ways around that), can't create views or tables.